# Arduino fails to connect with ethernet client

Tags: python, c, arduino, ethernet

In this GET request , I dont need an answer from the server , so the loop function is empty.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
IPAddress ip;
byte localIp[] = {192,168,1,181};
EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac , localIp);
  delay(1000);//give ethernet time to boot?
  byte x[] = { 192,168,1,1 };//my pc , running SimpleHTTPServer (python)
       client.connect(x , 8000);
       delay(1000);
       if(client.connected()){
        Serial.println("connected"); //does never print
       }
}

void loop()
{

}
```

The webserver of my pc does not receive any connection requests or so.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample is not even compilable. Here you are fixed version.

After you connect you better close connection with client.stop() otherwise some simple servers might not be listening for a new connection and are still waiting data to come on the previous connection.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
IPAddress ip;
IPAddress localIp (192,168,1,181);
EthernetClient client ;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac , localIp);
  char x[] = "192.168.1.1" ;//my pc , running SimpleHTTPServer (python)  
  client.connect(x , 8000);
  if( client.connected() ){
    Serial.println("connected"); //does never print
  }
  client.println ("Hellou world from Arduino!") ;
  client.stop();       
}

void loop()
{

}
```

Michal

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6e8ic4 It still doesnt work. + IPAddress = wrapper for byte so

Comment: Can you telnet the server? `telnet 192.168.1.1 8000`

Comment: Maybe it is due to your Windows firewall. Turn it off during the test.

Comment: Its off.This and antiviruses etc